# Android onStartCommand not starting

Tags: android

I want to call an intent when the mobile boots but for some reason the logs won't output except for the one in AutoStart

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(arg0,NotificationScheduler.class);
        arg0.startService(intent);
        Log.i("Autostart", "started");
    }
}
```

And the alarm handler whose logs are not outputting

```
public class NotificationScheduler extends Service {

    public NotificationScheduler() {
    }



    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.i("ALARMMAGNAGER", "started");
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        Log.i("ALARMMAGNAGER", "started");
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 9);

        Intent targetIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, targetIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), /*AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*/20000, pi);

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add service component in manifest file?

Comment: ugh I didn't...thanks a lot